# How to define variables cucumber steps in groovy?

Tags: variables, groovy, cucumber, katalon-studio

I don't know how to make groovy code with variables in Katalon Studio.
For example. I have step called: 
When I go to "sample site"

And i want to have this "When I go to" define in the way that if i put any link in quotes in Feature file it will actually take me there.

I show you what i tried:

Thats groovy step defintion:

```
    @When('I go to (.*)')
    def I_go_to() {
        WebUI.navigateToUrl('sample site')
    }
```

Thats step in Cucumber in feature file:

```
     When I go to "sample site"
```

However all i get is an error saying :

```
I go to "sample site" FAILED.
Reason:
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Step [I go to (.*)] is defined with 0 parameters at 'behat.StepDefinition.I_go_to() in file:/D:/Katalon/katalon-tests/katalon-tests/katalon-tests/bin/groovy/'.
However, the gherkin step has 1 arguments:
 * "sample"
Step text: I go to "/admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/category/overview"
    at cucumber.runtime.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.arityMismatch(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:84)
    at cucumber.runtime.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
@When('I go to (.*)')
def I_go_to() {
    WebUI.navigateToUrl('sample site')
}
```

you are telling the Cucumber to run the `I_go_to()` function that takes *no parameters*. And that function calls the `WebUI.navigateToUrl()` function that takes `'sample site'` as a parameter.

You need to pass whatever was here `(.*)` to your `I_go_to()` function. You can try with something like this:

```
@When('I go to (.*)')
def I_go_to(String url) {
    WebUI.navigateToUrl(url)
}
```